# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos^2(n)e^{-n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos^2(n)e^{-n}$ converge or diverge?

I think I need to use the comparison test but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$ and thus $| \cos^2(x) | \le 1$. If you want more, I suggest editing your question to include in more detail your understanding and attempts of the problem.

Comment: Compare to $\frac{1}{e^{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

Notice for all (real) $n$, $0 \leq cos^2(n) \leq 1$, and thus $0 \leq cos^2(n)e^{-n} \leq e^{-n}$. Then you can use the comparison test ($cos^2(n)e^{-n}$ with $e^{-n}$. Take it from here! :)

Good luck.

Comment: So taking the integral of e^-n results in it converging, so then the sum of e^n converges and therefore the original series converges, right? Also, does this mean it converges absolutley?

Comment: @strugglingchemist $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}e^{-n}$ is a geometric series, so that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}e^{-n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{e}}=\frac{e}{e-1}$. However, your series starts with $n=1$, not $n=0$, so we have to subtract off $e^{0}=1$, and we get $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}e^{-n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{e}}-1$. The comparison test reveals that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\cos^{2}(n)e^{-n}$ converges. And you're absolutely right: Since $\cos^2(n)e^{-n}$ is positive for every natural number $n$, your series actually converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we know that $0\leq\cos^2(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
0\leq\cos^2(n)e^{-n}\leq e^{-n}.
\end{align*}
for all natural numbers $n$.

You're right: the comparison test can be used to good effect here. Can you see how?